# #1052 - Column 'courses' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

Here's my code:

```
SELECT all_university.*, 
       all_colleges.* 
FROM all_university 
INNER JOIN all_colleges ON all_colleges.stateid = all_university.stateid 
WHERE courses LIKE '%BTech%'
```

Here I want all data from `all_university` and `all_colleges` where `stateid` is common in both table but when I run query, the where condition throws the error

```
#1052 - Column 'courses' in where clause is ambiguous. How can I remove this.
```

Thank You

Comment: yes, courses is present on both tables.

Comment: Use alias to distinguish. `all_colleges.courses`

Comment: use alias for common name fields

Comment: SELECT all_university . * , all_colleges . * FROM all_university as au INNER JOIN all_colleges ON all_colleges.stateid = au.stateid where courses like '%BTech%'

Comment: its shows error #1051 - Unknown table 'all_university'

Comment: SELECT au.* , ac.* FROM all_university as au INNER JOIN all_colleges as ac on ac.stateid = au.stateid where courses like '%BCA%'  again it shows error #1052 - Column 'courses' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify table with filed name in where clause. 
Your Query will be like this.

```
SELECT all_university . * , all_colleges . * FROM all_university INNER JOIN all_colleges ON all_colleges.stateid = all_university.stateid where all_university.courses like '%BTech%'
```

or

```
SELECT all_university . * , all_colleges . * FROM all_university INNER JOIN all_colleges ON all_colleges.stateid = all_university.stateid where all_colleges.courses like '%BTech%'
```

I dont know which table contain `courses` column. Thats why two query